# SQL query to return the number of users

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwhH.png)

SQL query to return the number of users assigned to the role with the RoleName ‘Administrators’.

```
SELECT RoleName count(*)
FROM Roles
WHERE RoleName = ‘Administrators’;
```

?????

Comment: That's nice.  Do you have a question?  I do note you need a comma in the `SELECT`.

Comment: SELECT RoleName,count(*)
FROM Roles
WHERE RoleName = ‘Administrators’ group by RoleName ;

Comment: @GordonLinoff He has 5 questions - it ends with 5 question marks ;)

Comment: Great username, @hellogoodbye ;) sounds like you will stay long here

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RoleName, count(*) as NumberOf
FROM Roles
WHERE RoleName = ‘Administrators’;
```

Or, to be more general and count number of each RoleName

```
SELECT RoleName, count(*) as NumberOf
FROM Roles
GROUP BY RoleName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
SELECT
  r.RoleName,
  COUNT(UR.Userid)
FROM Roles R
JOIN UserRole UR
  ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
GROUP BY r.RoleName
```

Comment: I still dont quite understand. Say I wanted query to return how many roles are assigned to the user with the FirstName 'Sam'.